# How can I create a function that can remove checkboxes from the classes upon checking them?

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox

I'm trying to create a task manager, I've got the adding of the task working, but struggling with the reverse. I want it, so that when I click on a checkbox, it will remove that checkbox and the description of it. There is something I'm doing wrong and I'm not sure what it is. I think I need an event handler or something, or maybe I'm not using remove() right, and I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. So everything from above `function deleteTask() {` is working.

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Overall Status</h2>

                <div class="sb">
                    <h3>School -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="schl.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

                <div class="sb">
                    <h3>Work -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="wrk.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

                <div class="sb">
                    <h3>Weekend -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="wknd.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

                <div class="sb">
                    <h3>Other -</h3>
                        <input type="submit" id="othr.bttn" value="0">
                </div>

         </div>

         <div id="tasks">
             <div id="newtask">
                 <h2>Add New Task</h2>


                 <div id="IDK">
                     <div id="idk">
                        <label for="options">Options*</label>
                            <select id="options">
                                <option hidden disabled selected value>------------------------------------------</option>
                                <option value="School">School</option>
                                <option value="Work">Work</option>
                                <option value="Weekend">Weekend</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                     </div>

                        <div id="idk2">
                            <label for="date">Completion Date</label>
                                <input type="date" id="date">
                        </div>
                 </div>

                    <label for="desc">Description*</label>
                        <input type="text" id="desc" size="75">

                    <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add">
                        <div id="req"><strong>* Required fields</strong></div> 
            </div>




              <div id="current">

                    <h2>Current Tasks</h2>

                          <div id="schlwrkwkndothr">

                              <div id="schl">
                                  <h3>School</h3>
                                  <br>
                              </div>

                              <div id="wrk">
                                  <h3>Work</h3>
                                  <br>
                              </div>

                                <div id="wknd">
                                  <h3>Weekend</h3>
                                  <br>
                                </div>

                                <div id="othr">
                                  <h3>Other</h3>
                                  <br>
                                </div>
                          </div>
              </div>



        </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;



function addTask() {

  var newTask = $("#desc").val();
  var newTask2 = $("#date").val();

  if ($("#options").val() == "" || $("#desc").val() == "") {
    alert("You have not completed all required fields.");

  } else if ($("#options").val() == "School") {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox1' }).appendTo($('#schl'));
    $('<label />', {  text: newTask+newTask2 }).appendTo($('#schl'));

  document.getElementById("schl.bttn").value = ++a;


  } else if ($("#options").val() == "Work") {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox2' }).appendTo($('#wrk'));
    $('<label />', {  text: newTask+newTask2 }).appendTo($('#wrk'));

    document.getElementById("wrk.bttn").value = ++b;


  } else if ($("#options").val() == "Weekend") {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox3' }).appendTo($('#wknd'));
    $('<label />', {  text: newTask+newTask2 }).appendTo($('#wknd'));

    document.getElementById("wknd.bttn").value = ++c;


  } else if ($("#options").val() == "Other") {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox4' }).appendTo($('#othr'));
    $('<label />', {  text: newTask+newTask2 }).appendTo($('#othr'));

    document.getElementById("othr.bttn").value = ++d;

  }

  $("#desc").val("");
  $("#date").val("");

}

$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#add").on("click", function() {
         addTask();
});
});








function deleteTask() {

if ($('.checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox1' }).empty($('#schl'));
    $('<label />', { text: newTask+newTask2 }).empty($('#schl'));

document.getElementById("schl.bttn").value = --a;


} else if ($('.checkbox2').is(":checked")) {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox2' }).remove($('#wrk'));
    $('<label />', { text: newTask+newTask2 }).remove($('#wrk'));

document.getElementById("wrk.bttn").value = --b;


} else if ($('.checkbox3').is(":checked")) {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox3' }).remove($('#wknd'));
    $('<label />', { text: newTask+newTask2 }).remove($('#wknd'));

document.getElementById("wknd.bttn").value = --c;


} else if ($('.checkbox4').is(":checked")) {
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox4' }).remove($('#othr'));
    $('<label />', { text: newTask+newTask2 }).remove($('#othr'));

document.getElementById("othr.bttn").value = --d;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your HTML? Also, `$('<input />', ... )` creates a new DOM element; anything you to do that element (e.g. `.remove()`) won't affect the current elements on the page.

Comment: I've added in all my HTML, so what do you suggest I do, to fix it up so that it will affect the current elements on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `deleteTask()` function. When you're adding the `<checkbox>` and `<label>` tags, bind them to an event listener that removes them when you click the checkbox:

```
$('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', value: newTask+newTask2, class: 'checkbox1' }).appendTo($('#schl')).click(handle_removal);
```

And the function that handles removal, regardless of which checkbox it is bound to:

```
function handle_removal(e){
    if( $(e.target).is(":checked") ) {
        var selector = 'input#' + $(e.target).parent().attr('id') + '-btn'; // Determine the ID of the input field
        var input = $( selector ); // Get the input field
        input.val( parseInt( input.val() ) - 1 ); // Subtract 1

        $(e.target).next().remove(); // Remove label
        $(e.target).remove(); // Remove checkbox
    }
}
```

This also requires that you change the names of your `<input>` fields (which display the counts for each category to:

```
<input type="submit" id="schl-btn" value="0">
<input type="submit" id="wrk-btn" value="0">
<input type="submit" id="wknd-btn" value="0">
<input type="submit" id="othr-btn" value="0">
```

The `handle_removal()` function takes the ID of the parent div (e.g. `schl`) and appends `-btn`, to derive the selector for the input field to decrement, e.g. `input#schl-btn`.

Comment: Ok, so it can now delete the tasks, however I want the "overall status" numbers to go down as well when you delete them and I'm not quite sure how to go about that, other than creating 4 different functions.

Comment: See my updated answer for how to decrease the counts.